# How to continue firing when button is touched?

Tags: unity

How to continuos firing when user touch (and keep press) a button in Android/iOs?

Using onClick, i can fire only one shot.

Is there an event like "keep-touch" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this example on using touch on Mobile devices:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html

Similarly you can use this code to use a boolean variable to start and stop shooting based on touch

```
// global
bool bContinuousShoot = false;

// In Update loop
for (var touch : Touch in Input.touches) {
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        bContinuousShoot = true;
        // You code goes here...
    } else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
        bContinuousShoot = false;
    }
}
```

TouchPhase reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html

Comment: [GetMouseDownButton](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) can be used as well.

Comment: You didn't take into account an important detail of the question : the asker wants continuous shoot when **pressing a button**. With this, he player will be able to contiously shoot, no matter where he touches the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are working with UGUI buttons, you can attach pointer down and pointer up listeners to the buttons. I haven't tested the following code, tell me if you have any problem.

```
// At the top of your file
using UnityEngine.UI ;

// ...    

// Class member
public float fireRate = 0.1f ;

// Drag & Drop the UI button in this field of the inspector
[SerializeField]
private Button shootButton ;

private bool continuousShoot = false ;

private float nextShootTime = 0 ;

private void Awake()
{
    if( shootButton == null )
        throw new Exception("You haven't assigned a button on the inspector");

    EventTrigger eventTrigger = shootButton.AddComponent<EventTrigger>( );

    // Pointer down
    EventTrigger.Entry pointerDownEntry = new EventTrigger.Entry( );
    pointerDownEntry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
    pointerDownEntry.callback.AddListener( ( data ) => { EnableContinuousShoot(); } );
    eventTrigger.triggers.Add( pointerDownEntry );

    // Pointer up
    EventTrigger.Entry pointerUpEntry = new EventTrigger.Entry( );
    pointerUpEntry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerUp;
    pointerUpEntry.callback.AddListener( ( data ) => { DisableContinuousShoot() ; } );
    eventTrigger.triggers.Add( pointerUpEntry );
}

private void Update()
{
    if( continuousShoot && Time.time > nextShootTime )
    {
        nextShootTime = Time.time + fireRate ;
        Shoot() ;
    }
}

private void Shoot()
{
    // Your code here
}

private void EnableContinuousShoot()
{
    continuousShoot = true ;
}

private void DisableContinuousShoot()
{
    continuousShoot = false;
}
```